# convert arrays of java objects in nested for loops to hashmap

Tags: java

I am working with two java objets. One of these object just have string attributes and the other one have strings and list of the first object.
The goal for me is to replace the double loops for a hasmap to reduce the time complexity. In this loop I do a equality check to see if some strings matches.

``

```
public class Object1 {

String name;

String xyz;

List<Object2> listObject2;

}

public class Object2 {

String name;

String abc;

String def;
}
```

Now in my main file I have the following function:

```
public fillNestedObject() {

List<Object1> listObject1 = new ArrayList();
listObject1 = fetchObjects1FromApi();

List<Object2> listObject2 = new ArrayList();
listObject2 = fetchObjectsFromApi2();

for(Object1 object1 : listObject1){
   List<Object2> tmpList = new ArrayList();
   for(Object2 object2 : listObject2) {
    if(object1.getName().equals(object2.getName())){
         tmpList.add(object2)
       }
   }
   object1.setListObject2(tmpList)
}
}
```

I'm pretty sure that to reduce the time complexity I can replace my double for loops by a hasmap (or 2?) but I am not sure how to do this because I want the equality to be true.
I read that I should use stream to convert into hasmaps on other questions but I am not sure how streams are gonna be used to achieve what I want.

Comment: This is so confusing. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to merge the contents of `Object1` and `Object2` into a single type (i.e. `Object1`)? If this is the case, I think you can create an adapter to do this.

Comment: Object 1 and 2 shares one attribut in common that is a name. I want to merge in a list of object 2 all the object 2 that has the same name. I updated with "better" attributes names for less confusion

Comment: You cannot replace a flow control structure for a data structure. You still have to look up matching value in two lists. What you can do is reduce the lists so that you don't keep looking up values that you already found. Since this implies deleting from lists, use an iterator so you could safely remove matched instances. Or better yet, use lambda expressions to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

First the Object2 stream is reduced to a map of the list of items with the same name.

Then retrieve the object 1 items from collect.

```
      Map<String, List<Object2>> reduced2 = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
              stream2.reduce(new HashMap<>(), (a, b) -> {
                         if (!a.containsKey(b.getName())) {
                            a.put(b.getName(), new ArrayList<>());
                         }
                         a.get(b.getName()).add(b);
                         return a;
                      }, (a, b) -> b));
      stream1.peek(object1 -> object1.setListObject2(reduced2.get(object1.getName())))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```